# Where can I find Conway's "All numbers, great and small"?

Tags: reference-request

I am doing research on the surreal number field and I would like to see the original papers by John Conway. I have attempted to obtain them but the results have been unsuccessful. I would like to know where to find this report.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for Conway's "On Numbers and Games", 1976? [This note](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~tf/ehrlichCameleon.pdf) seems to connect the above book to that quote.

Comment: Some of the results were also presented in Surrel Numbers, a novella by Don Knuth, https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/484458.Surreal_Numbers

Comment: Thanks for noting that this paper is contained in ONAG. Actually, Conway constructed the numbers on a research paper of the University of Calgary, no. 149, and then, Knuth published his book.

Answer (score 4):

It was published as the book "On Numbers and Games", still in print I think (I bought a copy 5 years back). Chapter 0 is still called "all numbers great and small" and lays out the definitions. There is also a re-edition (expanded) of Winning ways (for your mathematical plays), which builds on that book.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Found it! https://youtu.be/mPn2AdMH7UQ?t=83  "All Numbers Great and Small, Research Paper No. 149, Calgary, Alberta, Canada: The University of Calgary, Dept. of Mathematics and Statistics, 1972." https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266267540_All_Numbers_Great_and_Small  it's not exactly as cited but very close